# Zookeeper security concern

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Below is a well know problem about zookeeper safeguard. I might have limited knowledge or Zookeeper or may be I am trap in classical example of xy problem. So I am open to all kind of suggestion please do mention any thought.

If I want to run Zoookeeper quorum at 3 server having static IP. I have done all the configuration and

```
My quorum are distributed over 3 server which static ip , lets say 


server.1=xx.xx.x1:2888:3888
server.2=xx.xx.x2:2889:3889
server.3=xx.xx.x3:2890:3890


My concern is how should I protect it to other unauthorized zkClient to connect above quorum.
```

One way that I can think of, don't open the port for the client but then how will application 
( I am using this for solr) solr connect ?

other problem is how to safeguard quorum interconnection. I observed a weird behavior that I can point 
a fourth zookeeper from my local to the above quorum (i have to know only ip and port which is not tough 
to find) and it will be absorbed as a part of quorum and then I can use my local zkClient to connect my local 
zoookeeper and have access to quorum which we don't want. 
I want to define quorum in a way that foreign zookeeper server is not able to become part of it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to keep zookeeper on a private network not visible to the outside world?

Comment: Sir, that is my problem. I have static ip only may be I am not understanding clearly how to create private network.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the zookeeper programmer guide:

Particularly the bit about ACLs:
http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperAccessControl

> ZooKeeeper has the following built in schemes:
>
> world has a single id, anyone, that represents anyone. auth doesn't
>   use any id, represents any authenticated user. digest uses a
>   username:password string to generate MD5 hash which is then used as an
>   ACL ID identity. Authentication is done by sending the
>   username:password in clear text. When used in the ACL the expression
>   will be the username:base64 encoded SHA1 password digest. ip uses the
>   client host IP as an ACL ID identity. The ACL expression is of the
>   form addr/bits where the most significant bits of addr are matched
>   against the most significant bits of the client host IP.

Haven't used, but here's a guide to using:
https://ihong5.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/apache-zookeeper-setting-acl-in-zookeeper-client/

I'll try it out tomorrow!

Here's a guide to using this with Curator:
http://michaelmorello.blogspot.de/2012/12/zookeeper-netflix-curator-and-acls.html